# How to change requirement of form field based on object state?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-admin

Is it possible to change required attribute of form field based on object state (in modelforms and in admin - if possible)?

Eg: my DB model contains `status` field and depending of current object status, some other field should be required in certain status values and optional in other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even better, you can do it on the `Model` level.

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    .... some fields here...

    def clean(self):
        from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
        # Don't allow draft entries to have a pub_date.
        if self.status == 'draft' and self.pub_date is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Draft entries may not have a publication date.')
        # Set the pub_date for published items if it hasn't been set already.
        if self.status == 'published' and self.pub_date is None:
            self.pub_date = datetime.date.today()
```

Otherwise if this is not particularly tied to the db model, you can
similarly define the `clean` method of your model form.

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

Update: I just got the `required` attribute you mentioned.

There is no need to change dynamically the required attribute.
First of all RDBMS do not support that. Either there is a constraint
or there is not. So since this is business logic and not DB logic, 
you should put `null=True` on these fields(required=False, on form fields), and deal with them
as I've demonstrated above.

Comment: That was exactly what I was missing, I already had and `null=True` in model